# Show that sup norm can't be induced by any inner product (in any vector space)

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

In the following exercise:

> Use the parallelogram equality to show that the Sup-norm does not arise as an inner product.

there's no information about the vector space, so I assume it's applied for any vector space. For some specific vector space e.g $\mathit{C}([0, 1])$, $\mathscr{l}^1$, $\mathscr{l}^{\infty}$, I can show that it's true by constructing counter-examples for the parallelogram equality.

However, for arbitrary vector spaces, it seems hard to reconcile all the definitions of the sup-norm for various vector spaces to proceed. Is there any way to get around with this issue?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm My guess is that in your context, they meant the sup-norm on $\Bbb K^n$ ($\Bbb K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$). Is that exercise from a book? Is there an index at the end, mentionning "Sup-norm" with some page number? Or was that norm defined some pages before (in your book or lecture notes)?

Comment: @AnneBauval It's an exercise from Matthew's *Real Analysis* book, the index for "Sup-norm" references the definition of sup-norm on $\mathscr{l}^{\infty}$ specifically. So, if there's no way to prove it in an arbitrary space, it probably means the space $\mathscr{l}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: $C[0,1]$ is a normed space with the sup norm  $\displaystyle\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$.

Case 2: $\ell^\infty$ is a normed space with the sup norm $\displaystyle\|x\|_\infty = \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|$.

In the both cases, you should calculate, separately, $\|x+y\|^2_\infty +\|x-y\|^2_\infty$ and $2\left(\|x\|^2_\infty+\|y\|^2_\infty\right)$. Thus visualizing that in both cases, the **sup norm does not arise as an inner product**.

Comment: The answer is for specific cases but I'm asking for the general case.